I want prove that $ k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) \otimes_{k[t]} k \cong k[x,y]/(ay-x^{2}) $
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $a \in k$.
Let $k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) , k , k[x,y]/(ay-x^{2})$ be $k[t]$-module defined by the following.
$g(t) \cdot \Big(f(x,y,t) + (ty-x^{2})\Big) \rightarrow g(t)f(x,y,t) + (ty-x^{2})$ (natural product)($g \in k[t],f \in k[x,y,t])$
$g(t) \cdot b \rightarrow g(a)b, (g \in k[t], b \in k$)
$g(t) \cdot \Big(f(x,y) + (ay-x^{2})\Big) \rightarrow g(a)f(x,y) + (ay-x^{2}), (g \in k[t],f \in k[x,y])$
Let $\Psi : k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) \times _{k[t]} k \rightarrow k[x,y]/(ay-x^{2})$ be $(f(x,y,t) + (ty-x^{2}),b) \mapsto b\cdot f(x,y,a) + (ay-x^{2})$.
Then this map is well-defined and bilinear map, so there exist linear map 
$$ k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) \otimes _{k[t]} k \rightarrow k[x,y]/(ay-x^{2})$$
I want to prove this map is bijective. Clearly this map is surjective. But I don't know how to prove that this map is injective.
Let $\sum_{i} \Big(f_i(x,y,t)+(ty-x^{2})\Big) \otimes b_i \in k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) \otimes _{k[t]} k$ s.t. $\Psi (\sum_{i} \Big(f_i(x,y,t)+(ty-x^{2})\Big) \otimes b_i) = 0$.
$$
\Psi (\sum_{i} \Big(f_i(x,y,t)+(ty-x^{2})\Big) \otimes b_i) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Psi (\sum_{i} \Big(b_if_i(x,y,t)+(ty-x^{2})\Big) \otimes 1) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Psi \Big( \sum_{i}b_if_i(x,y,t)+(ty-x^{2})\Big) \otimes 1) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i}b_if_i(x,y,a)+(ay-x^{2}) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i}b_if_i(x,y,a) \in (ay-x^{2})
$$
Then if I prove $\sum_{i} b_if_i(x,y,t) \in (ty-x^{2})$, I can prove injectivity.
But can we actually show this?

You can lose the sum and work with just one polynomial $f(x,y,t)$ in the end. Also, note that the $b_i$ transfer over the tensor product is just one possible transfer, you can transfer any polynomial in $t$ that evaluated at $a$ is $b_i$. Can this happen for all such polynomials and we still have $f(x,y,a) \in (ay-x^2)$ and not $f(x,y,t) \not \in (ty-x^2)$? Probably some argument on the degree of $f$ works.

This question is similar to: Proving That $ \text{Spec}\Big( k[x,y,t]/(ty-x^{2}) \otimes_{k[t]} k (a) \Big) \cong \text{Spec}\Big( k[x,y]/(ay-x^{2}) \Big) $. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
